# Human Mortality database around the world

Tags: data-request, census

I am looking for a database about death rates and population around the world.

Idealy, I want:

- Per country
- Per year
- Including birth rates
- Divided by gender
- Including age of death

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The World Health Organization [Mortality Database](http://www.who.int/healthinfo/mortality_data/en/) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The CIA's [World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/) contains everything you ask except it has data for only one year.

Answer (score 3):

The United Nations Statistical Division publishes an annual yearbook of statistics (including birth/death rates) by country. The latest addition is 2012

http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/dyb/dyb2012.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no more reliable database than Human Mortality Database -- [mortality.org](http://mortality.org). This database is run by demographers who use state-of-the-art methodology to overcome issues in the data. As the result, the estimates are as precise as possible. Their [methods protocol](http://www.mortality.org/Public/Docs/MethodsProtocol.pdf) is a masterpiece of demographic data processing. On the down side, the data of decent enough quality is available for only a bunch of countries.

[image]

---

To explore the data I highly recommend [Human Mortality Database Explorer](https://jschoeley.shinyapps.io/hmdexp/).

[image]

---

For those who use R, a very handy acquisition package exists for HMD -- `HMDHFDplus`. A couple of examples how to use this package at my blog: [one](https://ikashnitsky.github.io/2017/hmd-all-sex-ratio/), [two](https://ikashnitsky.github.io/2017/hmd-male-mortality-rus-jpn/).